# traversing results of createSQLQuery using for-each

Tags: java, hibernate, foreach

Consider this:

```
//members is a table.
String sql="select * from members"; 

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List list = query.list();   

/***Ist part**This part is working well.******************************/

for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
    Object [] obj= (Object[])list.get(j);
    for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
        System.out.println(obj[i]);
}

/***2nd part********This part is not working.Why???******************/

    for( Object[] objArr : list){       //---------->(1)

         for(Object m:objArr){

        System.out.println(((Member)m).getFirstname());
        }
    }
```

What i want to ask is that why statement (1) gives following error despite that each element in ***list*** is array of Objects i.e. Object[]:

```
compile:

    [javac] E:\prac java progs\hiber3\src\Dao.java:45: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : java.lang.Object
    [javac] required: java.lang.Object[]
    [javac]             for( Object[] objArr : list){
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

Comment: try `for( Object[] objArr : (Object[])list)`

Comment: how come member_id is a table? the where clause can contain only  expressions with (column name operator value)

Comment: @ user998692: Typing mistake! I have made it correct.

Comment: @vanathi: it will give error: `[javac] found   : java.util.List
[javac] required: java.lang.Object[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is declared as `List`. This is a raw type, so the Java compiler doesn't know what is inside the list. All it knows is that it contain instances of `Object`, since ever class in Java extends Object. So

```
for (Object[] objArr : list)
```

doesn't compile, since you're trying to assign an object of type `Object` to a variable of type `Object[]`. A cast is needed to be able to do that.

So, there are two solutions. You know that the list actually contains `Object[]` instances, so you cast the list to `List<Object[]>`:

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
for(Object[] objArr : list) {
```

Or you cast every element of the list to `Object[]`:

```
for (Object o : list) {
    Object[] objArr = (Object[]) o;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `list` which is `List` (it means `List<?>`) to `List<Object[]>`.

I mean

```
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)query.list();
```